# Data visualization components to show structure of RoR application

Tags: data-visualization, charts, ruby-on-rails

I tried to find the best data visualization component for a Rails app, but I found only a few possibilities. The best component what I found is [Highchart organisation graph](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/organization-chart), but I need something different, because I need this component to show the 'organization' of an app, and I need connections in the same row (some models have a many-to-many association with the same model tables). Have you got any idea for a simple and pretty solution?